# How to make Multilingual Website in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, resources

I don't understand where to put the Resources and how can we take the value from that?

Comment: Seriously? You get a complete answer from another user and accept the one that basically says "Use that guys answer"? Nice usernames by the way...

Comment: Why did you flag Jony Singla's answer as the correct one? He is just saying "Look at Sohnee's answer". Is it because you both have "Singla" in your names? Is that also why you have already accepted Jony Singla's answer in 4 of your questions?

Comment: @Krisof, that is my guess. Flagged for moderator review in case this is just sock puppeting. All of Jonys answers are less than 10 minutes old while the real answers are 20+ days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You put all of your language resources into a resource (.resx) file. You will essentially have one resource file per language, but will all the same "Name" items, with their respective "Values" - For example...

```
MyResource.resx (this will be the default)
Name: Welcome
Value: Welcome

MyResource.de-de.resx  (this will be used for German text)
Name: Welcome
Value: Wilkommen
```

You can then use these resources all over your application.

In views:

```
<%= MyResource.Welcome %>
```

For more detail on localisation in general, visit these:

http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Localization.aspx